# spring security manipulate session variable

Tags: grails, spring-security, session-variables

with spring security i secure controllers in grails by annotation.

I have projects related to users in my modell

Question: if someone tries to manipulate i.e. the projectId (stored as session var) is it possible he can view projects which are not related to logged in user?

I could check every time if projectID in session belongs to the logged in user or do security hash on the projectID to make it harder to manipulate but i guess its an overkill?!

An other approache could be that users in my app are as well DB users so they restricted by the DB for accessing other data... just an idea of a friend but i guess as well overkill...

I know that the session var is serverside but im not sure if its save for manipulating by a user...

mybe i dont have to care about this thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your actual question is, since your post is hard to follow, but if you need instance-level security control, you should be using the Access Control Lists feature that Spring Security provides. It is a TON of application overhead, especially as the number of instances you need to secure grows, but it will keep people from seeing the wrong things.

That said, if there are other ways you can restrict access to entities, such as a simple SpEL rule, you will often find that you have a much cleaner, more simple security structure.